# Asus laptop won't turn on

Tags: laptop, battery

I think I ran the battery too low (I have one power cord that I share between two computers and I was stupidly trying to use both machines at the same time and lost track of how long this one had been unplugged). This is an Asus X44H, and now it won't power on. I tried removing the battery and holding down the power button for several minutes, but when I put the battery back in, it didn't turn on; the only sign of power I get is that the green light next to the light bulb symbol is turned on. I've tried leaving the computer plugged in for three or four hours, but so far nothing happens other than this green light's staying on. Is leaving the machine plugged in, say, overnight likely to help? Or is there something else I can do that could get this to power on again? Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Dell laptop. To fix it, I left the battery out and left it alone overnight. That solved the problem. But that might not work here.

Answer (score 4):

Some Asus laptop computers are notorious for having bad motherboards. I do not recall the exact model, but I bought a Asus laptop for my mother that had the same issue.

A couple of things:

1. Running the battery too low: There's no such thing. You also don't need to plug the computer for 3 hours to be able to use it. even if the battery is dead, just plugging it in, even without a battery will make it work.
2. Try to use the power cable on the other computer. If it works, then you know its not the cable.
3. If its not the cable, that means the battery could still be good or not, so you may have a more serious issue.

Some suggest doing the following: Removed the battery and unplug the power supply. Hold down the power button for 45 seconds. Then reinstall the battery and  lug in power supply. Push the power button and verify if it works.

If not, some also suggest resetting the bios by removing the battery, which you can definitely try to do very carefully.

If the computer was not dropped, or wet, I would suggest contacting Asus ASAP.

I found that even being out of warranty (by a couple of days) Asus preferred to fix my mother's computer for free than having another unhappy customer.

In that case, it was a faulty batch of motherboards, the reason why the computer was so cheap `=]`

Comment: Thank you so much--holding the power button down WITHOUT having the power cord plugged in was the key to getting the machine up and running again. I had never heard this advice before (I'd always been told to do this with the power cord in). As soon as I tried it, I got the standard "system shut down because battery reached a critical level" screen, and was able to log back in to Windows. Thanks again for your advice--it saved me several hours' work and a repair trip.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!. Please accept the answer when possible. Cheers!